# Element is given wrong id

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

In the fallowing xml I set the LinearLayout to `@+id/camera` but when I call `(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera)` I get a `ClassCastException: Button can not be cast to Linearlayout`. In other words, the id is some how applied to one of the buttons. if I remove the second `android:layout_above="@+id/camera"` then it works fine. What is going on here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    <View 
        android:id="@+id/center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/front"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="front"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center"
        android:layout_above="@+id/camera" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="back"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/center"
        android:layout_above="@+id/camera" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/export"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="export"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/camera" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Double check that you have not accidentally imported `android.R`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/front"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="front"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/camera" />
```

You should not use the `+` when referring to it the second time. `android:id="@+id/my_id"` means "I am adding this ID to the list of IDs and I want to use it as the id of this element."

`android:id="@id/my_id"` means "I want to use an existing id as the id of this element."

Comment: Please disregard my previous comment. I had to do a clean build, something must have been caching the old version.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to fix:

1. When referring to an element in a `layout_x` constraint, remove the `+`.
2. Be sure you have not accidentally imported `android.R`.

Comment: I have not imported `android.R`

Comment: re: point 1, it's not always the case. Consider a RelativeLayout where you'd refer to an element you haven't yet declared in the XML layout (i.e. an element below). In this case, you would have the "+", and when assigning the ID to the element, you would not have it.